# Weird font issue in IE and Chorme, but not Firefox, on certain websites

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, fonts

A few sites look really bad when viewed in IE.

[image: Example]

Can anyone tell what's the cause for this? This specific website uses a font called "Helevetica (Neue)" which we don't have on our systems but why does the site not switch to other provided fonts when the main font cannot be displayed?

When I switch the font to Arial using the accessibility options in IE, it looks good again. However, this option applies to all websites which we don't want.

The website looks fine when viewed in Firefox but the problem exists also in Chrome. It looks like Firefox just disables the font-family tag:

[image: disables the font-family tag].

Website: www.restaurant-aupremier.ch

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The crossed out CSS tag means that particular entry is being over-ridden by another rule.

Comment: Looks fine for me on IE11 (Win7).  Looks like you have a corrupted font.   The Font-Family is chosen form the list in order, based on availability.  Modify the tag and test each listed font-familty by itself, one at a time, until you find the one causing the problem on your system.  This will help us narrow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My helvetica font was corrupted.

It was actually installed but didn't show up in "system panel > fonts". However, there was still a registry key around. After deleting it and waiting for like 3 minutes, the page correctly used arial and looked fine again.

thanks for all help.